# SSRS- Complex Iff statements in changing background color

Tags: reporting-services

I am formatting the bottom rows of my report using the following expression

```
=IIf(Fields!EndPoint.Value="Total Sales Division"  or 
Fields!EndPoint.Value="Total End Point" or 
Fields!EndPoint.Value="Total IP-Relay" or 
Fields!EndPoint.Value="Total ClearCaptions","CornflowerBlue",
iif(Fields!Projection.Value="Actual","LimeGreen","LightBlue"
```

It works great until it hits columns with zero in it and formats the cell with the false resault being lightblue.  I did use =iif(isnothing(Sum(Fields!MnthSum.Value)),0,Sum(Fields!MnthSum.Value)) 
to insert zers's where I had blanks. I am assuming I must build that into my formula?

I have tried playing with this

```
=IIf(Fields!EndPoint.Value="Total Sales Division" and Sum(Fields!MnthSum.Value)=0 or 
Fields!EndPoint.Value="Total End Point" or 
Fields!EndPoint.Value="Total IP-Relay" or 
Fields!EndPoint.Value="Total ClearCaptions","CornflowerBlue",
iif(Fields!Projection.Value="Actual","LimeGreen","LightBlue"
```

this turns everything in that section lightblue and scipping the CornflowerBlue.

Any suggestions would be great and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add brackets to get your logic to evaluate correctly - probably like this:

`=IIf( ( Fields!EndPoint.Value="Total Sales Division" and Sum(Fields!MnthSum.Value)=0 ) or 
Fields!EndPoint.Value="Total End Point" or 
Fields!EndPoint.Value="Total IP-Relay" or 
Fields!EndPoint.Value="Total ClearCaptions","CornflowerBlue",
iif(Fields!Projection.Value="Actual","LimeGreen","LightBlue"`

Comment: I have done the following and I cannot get the CornflowerBlue to appear. Any other suggetions. =IIf( ( Fields!EndPoint.Value="Total Sales Division" and Sum(Fields!MnthSum.Value)=0 ) or 
Fields!EndPoint.Value="Total End Point" or 
Fields!EndPoint.Value="Total IP-Relay" or 
Fields!EndPoint.Value="Total ClearCaptions","CornflowerBlue",
iif(Fields!Projection.Value="Actual","LimeGreen","LightBlue"
              )
)

Comment: Sometimes you need to use `= CDec(0)` instead of just `= 0`. Also note text comparisons are case-sensitive.

Comment: I added this and checked spelling with no luck

Comment: =IIf( ( Fields!EndPoint.Value="Total Sales Division" and Sum(Fields!MnthSum.Value)=CDec(0) ) or 
Fields!EndPoint.Value="Total End Point" and Sum(Fields!MnthSum.Value)=CDec(0) or 
Fields!EndPoint.Value="Total IP-Relay" and Sum(Fields!MnthSum.Value)=CDec(0)  or 
Fields!EndPoint.Value="Total ClearCaptions","CornflowerBlue",
iif(Fields!Projection.Value="Actual","LimeGreen","LightBlue"
              )
)

Comment: My original code works fine until it hits cells that are blank and I replaced them with 0.  If the field returns a value it works fine.  Is this helpful at all. It is still skipping over the logic for ConflowerBule'.

Comment: "the field" - be more specific